# .NET Core Web Application, passing in an object to a controller and casting it always fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have a .NET Core Web application using ASP.NET MVC 6. I have a generic API controller for the most common CRUD operations.  The issue is that I have multiple different types of Ids. For example I have both int and Guid.

My generic Get controller looks like:

```
// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet("api/[controller]/{id}")]
public virtual async Task<IEntity> Get(object id)
{
    var myEntity = await _myRepository.FindAsync(id);
    if (myEntity == null)
        return ItemNotFound();

    return myEntity;
}
```

If I change the method parameters to take in an int instead of an object, it works fine. However, if I cast the object as an int I get an invalid cast exception. Is there a way to successfully cast the object as what I expect it to be?

Comment: does a string work?

Comment: That also throws an invalid cast exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether I agree with your design, is not within the scope of this question or answer. But to solve your issue, you can do this:

```
public virtual async Task<IEntity> Get(string id)
{
    var parsedId;
    if (int.TryParse(id, out parsedId))
    {
        // It was an integer
    }
    else 
    {
        if (Guid.TryParse(id, out parsedId))
        {
            // It was a Guid
        }
        else 
        {
            // It was neither so what do you want to do?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a solution to this problem, so I will mark it as the answer. I decided to go an alternate route by creating different base api controller classes for the different Id types because I also thought that this wasn't the best design.